# Normalise/join SQL Server tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have inherited a SQL server database which isn't normalised and is giving me headaches. I am not very experienced in SQL and maybe asking stupid questions but would appreciate any advice on how to go forward with the below scenarios.

I have three tables as follows:-

A table of results:

```
**ResId    CompId     Name     Result**
  1        1          Band A   2
  2        1          Band B   1
  3        1          Band C   3
  4        2          Band A*  2
  5        2          Band B   1
  6        2          Band C   3
```

A table of Bands current names:

```
**BandId    BandName**
  1         Band A
  2         Band B
  3         Band C
```

A table of names the bands were previously known as (linked on BandId):

```
**oldBandId    BandId    oldBandName**
  1            1         Band A*
  2            1         Band a 
  2            2         Band b
```

I am looking to consolidate the list of band names in the results table, replacing the band name with a bandId however the result table contains band names from both tables. First question should I create some sort of join table and use this as the bandId in the results table? If so What do I need in this join table, is it just a psuedo-Id of bandId/oldBandId and the table name concatenated then this placed in the results table?

I am then looking to use a query to select all results where the user selects the band by any name variant (new or old) and returns the results including all names linked with the band i.e. choosing Band A would return the results for both Band A and Band A*.

Thanks in advance

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your current db structure is fine enough - I can't think of any way to improve on it, without complicating it further (especially if you want to retain the old band names).

You can just write a query as so for your need -

```
select * from results
where Name = @bandName or
      Name in (select oldBandName 
                from oldBands
                where BandId in (select BandId 
                                from Bands
                                where BandName = @bandName))
```

Comment: Of course you can also improve on that by using exists instead of in.

Comment: I need to change the bandname to an id in the results table as I don't want a nvarchar field - I need to limit the input

Comment: Then why don't you make it two different columns in the results table? Either bandid and oldbandid - one will be null when the other one is filled. Or bandid and type ('new' or 'old').

Comment: Would that not be bad practice potentially have thousands of rows containing nulls when I could link on ids? I'm trying to normalise the db - I am new to this so if it's not possible then I will go down this route

Comment: If I do go down the route of concatenating the id and table name can I do a 'split' in a query so I know which table to query?

Comment: Split is more expensive - thousands of records is actually not much to worry about nulls - so no need to unnecessarily overengineer the application.. also the second option I gave above, with bandid and type, will not have that problem.

Answer (score 2):

I like the idea of using the band id in the results table. I would suggest eliminating the "old band name" table and replace it with a table of band aliases, since that sounds more like what you want.   The band alias table would just have the band id and an one alias per row.

Comment: I would still like to make a distinction between old and new as the old band table contains more data than shown - start and end dates, locations etc, so does that mean I need a separate alias table?

Comment: I did not realize it had more columns.  I would not convert it to a simple alias table, but I would possibly remove the oldBandId column.  And therefore just have one band id that each row is tied to.

Comment: I think for other parts of the system I still need the parent child structure between new and old so can't really go down the route of dropping the oldid